# ASP.NET not sending emails to my own domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, cpanel

I have two servers one linux server running cpanel/whm which act as a mail server and DNS Server for my domain and I host the website for the same domain on a different windows web server.

I have set up windows server with SMTP service to be able to send emails from my ASP.NET application.

Everything is going OK and my application sends emails correctly everywhere except to my own domain itself. If I sent and email to an email address like this somename@mydomain.com it is never delivered although sending emails using the same application to any domain succeeds.

Could you help me what should be the reason for this problem?

Regards,

Ehab Zaky

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by a setting on your SMTP Server itself.

Most smtp servers by default will not accept traffic if it claims to be from a local domain but is not a valid local user. So the first thing I would try is send the email from something that is a real working email address configured on your SMTP server. If that works, then you know what the problem is and can choose your course of action from there.

If that doesn;t work, then I would check the security settings of your SMTP server and look for limitations / restrictions regarding local domains. I am not a Linux user, but this seems to me to be whats probably happening.

Dave